# Using Azure ADB2C customized Sign Up / Sign In, is there a way to go directly to Sign Up Now link?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We've customized the Sign Up / Sign In, Profile Editing and Reset Password experiences for our AD B2C installation using the templates and have that working ok (the error messages and user experience is still kind of wonky) but the main question is that we have a use case where we know we have a new user and want to go straight to the account creation flow behind the Sign Up / Sign In dialog without needing the user to press the "Sign Up Now" link.  Since the Sign Up policy uses a different customization process which doesn't allow the use of custom HTML / Templates, that is not an option we'd like to use.  Is there a way to do that either through policy changes or code in the application?

Comment: can you source 'Since the Sign Up policy uses a different customization process'.  From what I know it supports the exact some stuff.

Comment: I have customized everything - the question is how to get that page to show up first, without having to display the Sign Up/Sign In dialog

Comment: create a sign-up policy and pass that policy name to your request to b2c and it will go directly to the sign-up screen

Comment: I understand that I could create a separate sign up policy, but then I need to keep the configuration the same as what is setup in the Sign Up / Sign In policy and make changes in both places - I wanted to know if it was possible to go straight to the Sign Up behind the Sign Up / Sign In dialog instead

Comment: I see now.  I doubt it but maybe else has some ideas on that.  good luck!

Comment: you might want to re-word your question. "in a sign-up/sign-in policy, can I send the user **directly** to the sign-up portion'

Comment: same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724207/b2c-open-registrar-form-instead-login-form, not possible...

Comment: So the really annoying thing about this is that the HTML from ADB2C that is injected into the div between the two sign up pages is just different enough that, unless you have something very generic, the style / CSS must be changed to work with each individually - one of the things I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to use the same page customization for sign-up policy.  [See this sample direct link to the a sign-up page.](https://login.microsoftonline.com/spottedmahnb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_Sign-up&client_id=d2e5807e-88c1-469a-a1c3-d7ae8738cdb4&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login)

[image: sample sign-up screen]

**B2C Configuration**

[image: sign-up policies link]

[image: sign-up policy configuration]

[Source of how to customize b2c pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization-helper-tool)