# B2C - Open registrar form instead login form

Tags: azure, authorization, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using Azure B2C authorization for my single app Azure functions.

I allowing user to login with google account or with user name / password.

In order to show login page I used msal library.

Now I have a situation, where I want to show user the registration page directly, and not first the login page and then he have to click create new account.

Is there a way to do it? with msal or a different library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, but you can create a "Sign up policy" and link directly to that.